# Why does my namespace and class name conflict?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, centos, puppet, ruby

I have a puppet module installed that is called `ntp`.

A node do I define by

```
node testip { include myconfig::ntpp }
```

and in `/etc/puppet/modules/myconfig/manifests/init.pp` have I

```
class myconfig::ntpp {
  include common
  class {'ntp':
      server_list => $common::data::ntpServerList
  }
}
```

This works perfectly.

But if I replace `myconfig::ntpp` with `myconfig::ntp` I get

```
Error: Could not retrieve catalog from remote server: Error 400 on SERVER: Duplicate declaration: Class[Myconfig::Ntp] is already declared; cannot redeclare on node testip
```

**Question**

Is it possible to have my node look like?:

```
node testip { include myconfig::ntp }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a design issue in puppet on how puppet tries to resolve the classnames. See [this ticket for more info](https://projects.puppetlabs.com/issues/2053) or [this link regarding namespaces](http://docs.puppetlabs.com/puppet/2.7/reference/lang_namespaces.html#relative-name-lookup-and-incorrect-name-resolution).

And you should try to access your top level `NTP` modules with

```
class { "::ntp":
   server_list => ...
}
```